# Jquery Ajax Post (onchange bucle infinito)

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, entity-framework, .net

Buenas gente   tengo el siguiente problema : Tengo un `dropdownList` que dependiendo de su valor me trae mediante `ajax` un formulario diferente con su respectivo boton,hasta ahi funciona bien.

```
    <div id="contformularios1">

    </div>



      $('#dropVal').on('change',function (e) {

      //$("#contformularios1").html("");
       var tipo = $(this).val();

        if (tipo == "1") {

        //carga el formulario
        var url = "/ZsvalDatabase/Create";
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            var forms = $("#contformularios1").html(data);
        });
        $("#boton2").hide();
        $("#boton3").hide();
        $("#boton4").hide();
        $("#boton1").show();
    }

    if (tipo == '2') {
        $("#boton1").hide();
        $("#boton2").show();
        $("#boton3").hide();
       // carga al formulario
        var url = "/ZsvalWorkflow/Create";
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            $("#contformularios1").html(data);
        });
        }


    if (tipo == '3') {
        $("#boton1").hide();
        $("#boton2").hide();
        $("#boton3").show();
        // carga al formulario

        var url = "/ZsvalSearch/Create";
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            $("#contformularios1").html(data);
        });
    }

    //if (tipo == '4') {
    //    //var url = "/ZsvalVariable/Create";
    //    //$.get(url, null, function (data) {
    //    //    $("#contformularios1").html(data);
    //    //});
    //}


       })
```

El error ocurre cuando inserto esos datos en `sql` mediante el siguiente boton :

```
    $("#boton1").click(function (ev) {

    var obj = {
        Id: 1,
        Cid: $("#cid").parents().children("select").val(),
        query: $("#query").parents().children("input").val(),
        Result: $("#result").parents().children("input").val(),
        Connection: null,
    }

    //envia el objeto
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        url: "/ZsvalDatabase/Create",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)

        },
    })
    ev.preventDefault();

})
```

En vez de insertar el Objeto solo 1 vez,lo hace tantas veces como yo haya llamado diferentes formularios mediante el `dropdownlist`.
Osea si selecciono el tipo 1,luego selecciono el tipo 2 y luego nuevamente el 1 y lo inserto se me genera un `loop` que me inserta 3  o mas objetos

```
    public ActionResult Create(Zsvdb zsvdb)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Zsvdb.Add(zsvdb);
            db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        ViewBag.Cid = new SelectList(db.Connection, "Id", "Cname", zsvdb.Cid);
        //return Json(zsvdb, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return View(zsvdb);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Es que deberias tener dos metodos `Create` uno que actue en el `GET` y otro en el `POST`

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   //aqui accedes al contexto para recupera la lista
   return View(zsvdb);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Zsvdb zsvdb)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      db.Zsvdb.Add(zsvdb);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Veras que un metodo se define como `[HttpPost]` entonces separas las oepraciones, cuando haces el `GET` no estas realizando el `SaveChange()`